# jQuery how to swap ID between classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvNCz/11/)

I am trying to style my "current" navigation tabs. I also have a hover script in jQuery which is causing difficulties doing this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav1" id="current"><a href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li><span>.</span></li>
    <li class="nav2"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li><span>.</span></li>
    <li class="nav3"><a href="#">Links</a></li>
    <li><span>.</span></li>
    <li class="nav4"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

//This bit does not work as expected. -->
$(".nav li a").click(function(){

    $("li#current").removeAttr('id');
    $(this).parent().attr("id","current");

});
```

Basically I need to move the id from the first li anchor to whichever other li anchor is clicked, and have this newly placed id recognised by the hover script.

E.g. When you click "Articles", "Images" disappears in blue, and "Articles" appears in blue and stays visible once the mouse is moved.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to add extra class `current`on selected item -- `class="nav1 current"`

```
$(".nav li a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
});
```

Should be like that ... have to check it.

EDIT: Yes it works.

Comment: Thanks reflective, took a few hours hacking around but I got the answer I needed from this!

Answer (score 0):

You don't swap IDs or names in html, only classes and other transient attributes. Otherwise you'd cause side effects when code expects an Id to be on a specific item. Think of it as changing your social security number because you had a blue shirt on for the weekend.

Add a current class to your CSS and toggle it on and off on the elements depending on what is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mvNCz/17/
Basically you reversed the logic - you should swap classes and not id.

```
$(".nav li a").hover(function(){
    var other = $("#" + $(this).parent().attr('id') + "x");
    other.addClass("hovered");
    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        other.removeClass("hovered");
    });
});
$(".nav li a").click(function(){
    $("li.current").removeClass('current');
    $("#" + $(this).parent().attr('id') + "x").addClass("current");
});
```